# How to make C# class declaration text in Visual Studio workspace

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use Visual Studio 2010.

I want to make C# class summary text that includes only declarations without definitions.
When I use C++, I write class declaration in header file and write its definition in cpp file,
so I could get class summary text by copying header text. It's short and simple.

But in C#, declarations and definitions are in same place, so I can't copy that includes declarations only.

Is there a good way to solve it?
The way I hope is not by programming but by manual operation in workspace.

Example:

```
// Class definition
public class MyInfo
{
    public static char c = 'A';
    private int i = 0;

    public bool foo()
    {
        return i > 0;
    }

    public int bar(string a, int b)
    {
        return a.Length - b;
    }
}

// I want class summary text as below
public class MyInfo
{
    public static char c = 'A';
    private int i = 0;
    public bool foo();
    public int bar(string a, int b);
}
```

I think that class summary text is very useful to describe class in any place. For example, I can describe class by copying its text in mail body or web site content.

Comment: Maybe you want an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b(v=vs.80).aspx)?

Comment: I want to generate that like interface text from existing class definition.

Comment: VS too ! Refactor -> Extract Interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio there is a refactoring option "Extract Interface". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3dyx26.aspx In the interface you can have the comments in the same place with declaration of public api.

But I highly recommend using ReSharper, which has a lot of more and sophisticated refactoring options - it makes your Visual Studio "a little Intellij Idea"; it's definetely worth the money.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to use "Extract Interface" of default VS and one of ReShaper, then both worked well.
If I had my way, I wish it included also member declarations.